# Add mailto: with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

```
<table id="here" border="1">
    <tr><td>London</td><td>london@us.uk</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Manchester</td><td>manchester@us.uk</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Liverpool</td><td>liverpool@us.uk</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ipswich</td><td>ipswich@us.uk</td><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>
</table>
```

Is possible add link mailto: for second columns with email addresses with jQuery (not modify HTML)? If yes, how?

http://jsfiddle.net/zwsMD/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just replace the contents of each second `td` with an `a` element with a `mailto:` href: http://jsfiddle.net/zwsMD/5/.

```
​$("#here td:nth-child(2)").each(function() {
    var email = $(this).text();

    // replace contents
    $(this).html(
        $("<a>").attr("href", "mailto:" + email).text(email)
    );
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
​$('td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
   var text = $(this).text();
    var href = "mailto:"+text;
    var $a = $('<a>', { href: href, text: text});
    $(this).text('').append($a);
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

fiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/zwsMD/6/

Comment: @pimvdb yes yes, of course, i added var itwas a stupid mistake!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's always the second `td` of each row, you could iterate over those elements and [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) the [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) in an `a` element:

```
$("#here td:nth-child(2)").each(function() {
    $(this).contents().wrap("<a href='mailto:" + $(this).text() + "'>");
});​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zwsMD/2/).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to loop around every row, find the cell you want and wrap a link around the content. You can use [`wrapInner`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) for this.

```
$("#here tr").each(function() {
    var td = $(this).children().eq(1);
    var email = "mailto:" + td.text();
    td.wrapInner($("<a>").prop("href", email));
});​
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zwsMD/7/)